# backbone.js switch between localstorage and rest- api

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, local-storage

I like to create a basic todo- List App to improve my backbone- knowledge. This List app should switch between localstorage and content served by some REST- Api.

```
var FSEList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: FSE,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("liste")
});
```

How is it possible to change the source of the collection if some router gets triggered? Would be great if anybody  could help me.

Thanks in advance
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the Backbone.sync method to acomplish this.

```
var oldSyncMethod = Backbone.sync; // if you want to save the original method
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    if(this.offline) {  // if offline use local storage
        return Backbone.loaclSync.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    else { // otherwise use REST
        return Backbone.ajaxSync.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

You could use some feature detection to determine if the user is offline and store local in that case or use both local and rest at the same time. That depends on your needs.